# New way to close a flagging dialog

Tags: feature-request, flag-dialog, close-dialog

Due to a recent change, you can close flagging (and closing) dialogs by clicking anywhere on the page, except the dialog itself.<sup>1</sup> Let me be the first to say that I find this pretty annoying.

It is very easy to close the dialog by mistake when, e.g., using a touchpad to scroll to a different part of the page. Furthermore, it makes it impossible to copy and paste anything from the page itself into the *other* field if the dialog is already open. To make matters worse, reopening the flagging dialog wipes the *other* field clean.

I like this behavior for the little popups, but you can close the flagging dialog using either the big, bold **X** in the upper right corner or by just pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>. That's enough for me.

So:

- Can we please revert to the old behavior?
- In case the answer is no<sup>2</sup>, could the content of the *other* be restored when the dialog gets reopened?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Also, the **close** link in the lower left corner has disappeared, but I couldn't care less personally.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Requesting to undo recent changes seldom goes well.</sub>

Comment: Closing by clicking anywhere on the dialog seems... non-standard, so I favor this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Out of the dialog, not on the dialog. It is kinda non-standard when the rest of the page isn’t disabled anyways, though. Anyway, I second this: even Ctrl+clicking on a link in the background will close the dialog, which is sometimes annoying when reviewing duplicate close votes.

Comment: @minitech: Thanks, it's been a long day. :)