# Stop middle mouse button from closing the flag dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, user-interface, flag-dialog

I recently spent a couple of minutes writing a message to the diamond moderators, only to lose it when I middle clicked outside the flag dialog to activate autoscroll and the dialog unexpectedly closed. A little testing reveals that middle clicking links elsewhere on the page also closes the flagging dialog. This seems to be a reappearance of this bug, which was apparently fixed previously:
[StackExchange popup closes when using middle click](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66108/stackexchange-popup-closes-when-using-middle-click).

It's not the biggest problem in the world, but a fix would be nice.

Comment: It's not only a middle click, it's any click outside of the dialog

Comment: Related: [New way to close a flagging dialog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170831)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is fixed: only left clicks will close pop ups now.

It will be pushed out in the next deployment later today.